# Updated AWS CLI for EC2 via Ansible throws boto errors

Tags: python, aws-cli

I'm seeing an odd issue where after updating the AWS CLI from 1.10.1 to 1.10.60, running ec2 commands through Ansible no longer works.

i.e., running:
`local_action: "shell AWS_PROFILE=dev-aws aws ec2 describe-instances --debug --filters 'Name=instance-state-name,Values=running' 'Name=tag:Role,Values=ms_bastion'"`

... through Ansible throws this stack trace:
   
  `File \"/usr/local/bin/aws\", line 23, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 49, in main
    driver = create_clidriver()
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 58, in create_clidriver
    event_hooks=emitter)
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/plugin.py\", line 44, in load_plugins
    modules = _import_plugins(plugin_mapping)
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/plugin.py\", line 61, in _import_plugins
    module = __import__(path, fromlist=[module])
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/handlers.py\", line 66, in <module>
    from awscli.customizations.s3.s3 import s3_plugin_initialize
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/s3.py\", line 15, in <module>
    from awscli.customizations.s3.subcommands import ListCommand, WebsiteCommand, \\
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/subcommands.py\", line 24, in <module>
    from awscli.customizations.s3.fileinfobuilder import FileInfoBuilder
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/fileinfobuilder.py\", line 13, in <module>
    from awscli.customizations.s3.fileinfo import FileInfo
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/fileinfo.py\", line 9, in <module>
    from botocore.compat import MD5_AVAILABLE
    ImportError: cannot import name MD5_AVAILABLE`

Comment: Try updating your `botocore` package

Comment: I updated botocore from 1.4.50 to 1.4.51.... alas, same error

Comment: `MD5_AVAILABLE` appeared in `botocore.compat` starting from `v1.3.30`. Is it possible that you have two versions of `botocore` installed (for `python2.7` and `python3.x`). The one for `python2.7` seems to be out of date. Check it like this: `grep __version__ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/__init__.py`